# CakePHP 1.3: unable to turn off debugger in beforeFilter()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm unable to turn off the debugger for an action that send out an email for some reason. The email contains debugging messages in it. Below is the code that I use. I have `Configure::write('debug', 2)` in `core.php` as this is a development environment. I've also tried putting the `beforeFilter()` in the `AppController` but that doesn't do anything either. There is no other action named `email`. Is there something wrong with this code?

I'm also using the `DebugKit.Toolbar` Component. When I set `Configure::write('debug', 0)` in `core.php`, the extra messages in the email go away as well.

```
class TestsController extends AppController {
            ...

    function beforeFilter() {
        if(in_array($this->action, array('email'))) {
            Configure::write('debug', 0);
        }
    }

    public function email() {
                // send email
                ...
            }
}
```

The extra messages I get in the email are

```
<!-- Starting to render - email\text\test_text_message -->
 *email content here*
<!-- Finished - email\text\test_text_message -->
```

Comment: If you are using the component etc you will already have initialized it with debug 2 long before you actually turn debug off. you would need to manually create the component afterwards for your overwrite to work. Or just set debug to 0 earlier (in constructor etc). It still feels a little bit dirty to do what you are doing.

Comment: @mark How would the email contain debug messages. Those would only appear during rendering of the email template. All other output should no go into the email.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I'm using the `DebugKit.Toolbar` Component.

Comment: The email contains these debug kit messages that are inserted on debug > 0. as already explained beforeFilter() is triggered too late. Thats all there is to it.

Comment: @mark yea, I looked at debug kit source code. It's using the event manager to add render messages. kind of clever idea actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to disable for the entire controller.

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);

class TestsController extends AppController {
            ...

    public function email() {
          // send email
          ...
    }
}
```

That should turn off debug before any of the inner components are initialized, but after bootstrapping has completed so `Configure` is accessible.

Comment: Hmm this works! But I'm not sure why the `beforeFilter()` won't work. Do you have any idea? I'd like to disable it for a certain action, if possible.

Comment: @Youn, I don't but the debug message you're getting isn't one I've seen before. I haven't use DebugKit but the CakePHP email component doesn't render anything until you send the email. So it's strange.

Comment: @Youn oh I bet they have hooked into Views somehow to get callbacks on renders. So turning off debug in the beforeFilter is likely to late as the hooks are already set. You would also have to unhook DebugKit.